# Generics Subtyping issue in java

Tags: java, generics

I am trying to learn Subtyping in Java and I am not an better person in generics so I am getting this issue or doubt-

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;

interface Animal<T>{}
class Lion implements Animal<Lion>{}
class Butterfly implements Animal<Butterfly>{}
class Cage<T>{
    public <T> void addAnimal(T t){

    }
}

interface CageAnimal<E> extends  Collection<E>{}
public class SubType<T> {

    public <T> SubType() {
        Lion lion = new Lion();
        Butterfly butterfly = new Butterfly();      
        /**
         * **Here inside Lion cage, we added Butterfly : WRONG**
         */
        Cage<Lion> cageLion = new Cage<Lion>();
        cageLion.addAnimal(lion);
        cageLion.addAnimal(butterfly);


        CageAnimal<Lion> cageAnimalLion = (CageAnimal<Lion>) new ArrayList<Lion>();
        cageAnimalLion.add(lion);

        //cageAnimalLion.add(butterfly);//Butterfly is Not Supposed to add here as it is the cage of Lion
    }   
}
```

In the above example when I declare Cage , why I am able to add Butterfly and in the Same case when I made CageAnimal type, I am not able to add any Buttefly

```
Cage<Lion> cageLion = new Cage<Lion>();
cageLion.addAnimal(lion);
cageLion.addAnimal(butterfly);
```

and in case of Cage

```
Cage<Animal> cageAnimalLion = new Cage<Lion>();
cageAnimalLion.addAnimal(lion);
cageAnimalLion.addAnimal(butterfly); //Throwing Compile Error
```

Comment: You can't just cast an `ArrayList` to a `CageAnimal` like that. What exactly is your question?

Comment: My Question is Qhy in Cage class I am able to add Butterfly where I am adding generic type as Lion

Comment: I'm repeating myself, but don't declare Animal as interface Animal<T>, but simply as interface Animal. In that way you don't have the redundancy of typing Lion implements Animal<Lion>, which essentially says "Lion is an Animal of type Lion" - this doesn't add any functionality.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line

```
 public <T> void addAnimal(T t){
```

should probably be

```
 public void addAnimal(T t){
```

Comment: what is difference between previous and the new edited method type

Comment: The first is a generic method, which can be called with any type - this is useful if addAnimal would return T for example. Note that this "T" doesn't correspond to the "T" of your Cage class!

Comment: Exactly. In Eclipse, you'll get a compiler warning saying something like "method type parameter `T` shadows class type parameter `T`."

Answer (score 4):

Declare `Cage` class like this:

```
class Cage<T extends Animal> {
    public void addAnimal(T t) { ... }
}
```

If you declare the `addAnimal` method in the following way...

```
public void <T> addAnimal(T t)
```

... you are "hiding" the `T` type parameter with a **different** type parameter with the same name. It is the same as if you declared the method like this:

```
class Cage<T extends Animal> {
    public void <X> addAnimal(X t) { ... }
}
```

...which is obviously not doing its job. On the other hand, in the first version I wrote, both the `T` in declaration of the class and the method are the same.

Moreover declaring `<T extends Animal>` bound ensures that the cage can only be of type that extends an `Animal`, i.e. `Cage<Lion>`, `Cage<Butterfly>`, but `Cage<String>` is illegal.

And of course, you cannot cast an `ArrayList` to `CageAnimal`, that will fail at runtime with a `ClassCastException`, because `ArrayList` in not a subtype of `CageAnimal`.

Comment: In addition interface Animal<T> should really be just interface Animal. Lion implements Animal<Lion> sais "Lion is an Animal of type Lion", which is redundant and unnecessary.

Answer (score 3):

Because `CageAnimal` and `Cage` are very different things. Looks how you've defined generic parameter for `Cage`:

```
public <T> void addAnimal(T t){

}
```

This `<T>` you put on the method, means that method has its own generic parameter, different from the one you've defined in class. If you remove it from method signature it will use generic parameter of the class.

E.g.

```
public void addAnimal(T t)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that fundamentally your `Cage` will accept any `T`, and therefore any `Animal`. The various `T`'s don't all refer to the *same* value of T, they're variables local to the class or method.

What you could write is something like this:

```
public class Cage<T> {
  public void addAnimal(Animal<T> caged) {
  }
}
```

Now you will at least get compiler errors in the common case of:

```
Cage<Lion> c=new Cage<Lion>();
c.add(new Butterfly()); // should error AFAIK
```

However it will be reduced to a warning in case of:

```
Animal butterfly=new Butterfly();
Cage<Lion> c=new Cage<Lion>();
c.add(butterfly); // warning about raw types... IIRC
```

Because, fundamentally `Cage` will still accept any `Animal`.

EDIT: Note that the earlier mentioned answer of removing the `<T>` local to the `addAnimal` method will work better for this purpose.

Answer (score 2):

By declaring `public <T> void addAnimal(T t)` you're parameterising the method as well as the class `Cage`. This `T` has no relation to the `T` in `Cage<T>`.

You can either have:

```
class Cage<T extends Animal<T>> {
    public void addAnimal(T animal) {
    }
}
```

or, if you want the `Animal` returned then have:

```
class Cage<T extends Animal<T>> {
    public T addAnimal(T animal) {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
class Cage<T>{
    public <T> void addAnimal(T t){

    }
}
```

The Cage class has a generic method addAnimal. The generic type associated with the method causes the generic type associated with the class to be ignored and the type of the parameter to be used as the generic type for the method.

Try executing the following example to see what is happening:

```
public class TestCage {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Cage<String> cage1 = new Cage<String>();
        cage1.addAnimal(new String("test1"));
        cage1.addAnimal(new Integer(1));
        cage1.addAnimal2(new String("test2"));
        //cage1.addAnimal2(new Integer(1));  //Uncomment to throw error
    }

}

class Cage<T>{
        public <T> void addAnimal(T t){
              System.out.println("T: " + t.getClass().getName());
        }

        public void addAnimal2(T t){
              System.out.println("T: " + t.getClass().getName());
        }
}
```

In summary, by adding a generic method to the class, the generic type parameter of the class is ignored and the type of the parameter passed into the method is used as the generic type parameter of the method.

Answer (score 1):

Try to take the `<T>` out of `public <T> void addAnimal(T t)`.